# Issue in mounting host directory through docker file, retrieving unable to open file .h5

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-volume

I am trying to create an image from the below docker file

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3
RUN pip install -q keras==2.3.1 
RUN pip install pillow 
RUN mkdir -p /edge_app/src WORKDIR /edge_app/src 
COPY model_1.py /edge_app/src 
EXPOSE 31700 
VOLUME ["/testdata"] 
CMD ["python", "model_1.py"]
```

my tree structure is

```
├── data
│   └── predictions_result.npy
├── Dockerfile
├── m1.h5
├── model_1.py
├── testdata
│   ├── 0.jpg
│   ├── 10.jpg
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   ├── 2.jpg
│   ├── 3.jpg
│   ├── 4.jpg
│   ├── 5.jpg
│   ├── 6.jpg
│   ├── 7.jpg
│   └── m1.h5
```

model_1.py file

```
import  socket,keras,sys,os,csv,subprocess,time,shutil
from keras.preprocessing import image
from socket import *
import numpy as np
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19,preprocess_input,decode_predictions
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array,load_img
from keras import models,layers,Model,Input
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model

 model=load_model('m1.h5',compile=False)

 images=[]
 for img in os.listdir('testdata'):
     img=os.path.join('testdata', img)
     img=image.load_img(img,target_size=(224,224))
     img=image.img_to_array(img)
     img=np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
     img=preprocess_input(img.copy())
     images.append(img)
 images=np.vstack(images)
 predictions=model.predict(images)
 np.save('/workdir/data/predictions_result',predictions)
```

Running the Docker image through below command

```
sudo docker run --rm  -it tensor-keras
```

When I try to run the above docker run command in linux I retrieve the below error help is highly appreciated thanks for your wonderful help

```
  OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'm1.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Comment: The only file you're `COPY`ing into the image is the Python source; none of the actual data is there.  If you `docker run --rm -it tensor-keras bash` it will launch a temporary container with a debugging shell and you can see what got put into the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze, Thank you your help is highly appreciated. I use this command docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/workdir -w /workdir tensor-keras, its working fine.any suggestion how would I change my Dockerfile to accomplish this.

Comment: You can never specify host directories or otherwise force the use of host resources in a Dockerfile.  (You could include a `WORKDIR` directive to replace that `-w` option.)  You might consider a Python virtual environment as an even lighter-weight isolation scheme that doesn't require special permissions but can directly use host files without special setup.